# Uniquely identify an Android device: UUID vs. InstanceID

Tags: android

I would like to identify my user's devices in order to send push notifications. Previously I had been using IMEI but IMEI requires some extra permissions and also tablets don't have IMEI.

So I thought about updating the id system, and saw that Google itselfs recommends using InstanceIDs.

This seems like a fine method but has 2 caveats:

1. Tokens might change, which implies managing them in my backend server to refresh them and remove the old ones
2. Requires the user to have Google Play Services. How big is this requirement? Don't all users have Google Play Services already?

The other solution they propose is using a UUID, but how unique is really this number? Do I have to prepare for collision using this method?

Comment: *Don't all users have GPS already?* no

Comment: @TimCastelijns is there a stat on that?

Comment: I don't know but I believe it depends on the country of the user and or the device manufacturer

Comment: So using this InstanceID token is not really a good choice then, since it creates this dependency. Would you go for the second option?

Comment: I don't use either, I use app installation id for identification. Nothing is perfect but it works for me

Comment: Im sorry which id is that?

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the android id provided by Android framework. This is generated when the device is setup. This does not require any extra permissions.

`Settings.Secure.getString(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
                   Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);`

Edited:
in some cases(factory reset) this will change. for those cases you can use: This is being used for

`final String deviceId = ((TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getDeviceId();
    if (deviceId != null) {
        return deviceId;
    } else {
        return android.os.Build.SERIAL;
    }`

Comment: There are several threads about this issue explaining that this might be not unique

Comment: This is will get reset after factory reset. and your GCM is not going to reach the device.

Comment: Your push GCM id that you will send to the server along with the android should be refreshed after some intervals. because they can change. This is what is recommended.

Comment: yes for gcm to work you should have google play services

Comment: **TelephonyManager** solution is highly undesirable, as it requires asking for runtime permissions on users' devices to read their phone state.  This, in turn, will make some users suspicious - and rightfully so.